# Control method call rate in web application

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc

I have a method in service in a web application which call another third party web service to  fetch data. They have a restriction of sending maximum one call per sec.
How can i limit that hit rate in my method. A solution with some kind of queuing will be great.
I am using java and spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use Google Guava library and use [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html)

> [...] rate limiter distributes permits at a configurable rate. Each acquire() blocks if necessary until a permit is available [...] Rate limiters are often used to restrict the rate at which some physical or logical resource is accessed

There is a nice post describing its usage - [RateLimiter - Discovering Google Guava](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ratelimiter-discovering-google).